# Accessing a local device host with IP ending in 0

Tags: linux, networking, routing, netmask

I have made a mistake in setting up a headless embedded Linux device on a network. I left the static IP set to 10.10.10.0 with its subnet set to 255.255.255.0, which is of course an impossible combination (as I have now learned). Unfortunately, the device has some important data that would be very unfortunate to lose if it were factory reset.

However, if I run arp -a on windows connected directly to the device I am still able to see the device's IP and correct MAC. This gives me hope, however I can not access it through SSH or use the web config console.

I have an old DD-WRT router and tried setting some things up with a /16 netmask but had no such luck connecting. I have also tried with Xubuntu 16.04, removing firewalls without success. At this point completely out of ideas!

Comment: What type of device is it?  Is there no other way to connect to it?  I'm not sure how a configuration tool could allow such a bad IP address but that is obviously not reachable.

Comment: The combination isn't impossible. The broadcast address has a special meaning as IP destination and is reserved, but the network (zero) address doesn't have the same kind of special meaning, and appears to be usable as a host address.

Answer (score -1):

In the machine you want to connect to the embedded Linux box, set the ip to be 10.10.10.1 and subnet 255.255.0.0. There is nothing wrong with the IP of the embedded, but subnet mask is wrong. The subnet mask should only be used to decide if a packet should be sent to default gateway. To prevent it from that your connecting machine must be in the scope of the embedded's subnet mask.

On the other hand, as the ip/mask is an impossible combination, can it be that your settings were not accepted which means it went back to its older setting? Are you sure you can't reach it with another protocol than IP? Just some suggestions from the top of my head.

Comment: I do know that the IP address was accepted by the device as arp -a (on Windows 7 and 10) does show the address as it was set and valid MAC.
 
That configuration you mentioned was the first thing I tried and I still was not able to ping or connect to the device.

Comment: No RS232, no USB, no other interface? Anyways, if this is IP implementation on Linux embedded I think you've got a valid complaint against they who made it. It actually means it cares about mask at ingress, while it should only do that at egress. Assuming your embedded device accepted the IP, which it shouldn't if caring about mask at ingress, we can conclude that its IP is actually processed as a null route. Only used for dropping packets and count them in statistics.

Comment: There is TTL serial test points on the board which I will try and solder to. I do not have documentation or support for this device as it was donated for a robotics project.

Thanks for the suggestions :)